# How to embed icalendar on webpage

Tags: web, embed, icalendar

Just want to ask if any one has any idea how to embed an apple icalendar to a webpage? Apparently you can't do this directly using an iframe with the webcal:// address.

Answer (score 2):

Best I can figure, based on Googling it and trying, is that it can't be done at the moment. Wordpress.com lets you but I don't think they let you see the inner workings.

What I did was insert Google Calendar and sync it with iCal. The nice thing is you can apply css to Google Calendar and they make it very easy to insert Google calendar and it can display a a list (great for seeing more than one months worth of stuff), as a calendar month or just show one week.

Hope that helps.